# Fiddler monitor android app https traffic failed (seems be blocked by that app?)

Tags: networking, https, certificate, fiddler, traffic

For example:

1. There is an app `A`.
2. There is page `X` in `A`.
3. There is a button in `X` page used to sign in dayly to get some points.

What I want is catch and analyze the post traffic, and simulate an action to get the points every day, so I don't need do it myself. The first thing is use fiddler to monitor the traffic.

About fiddler:

1. I have already setup fiddler to monitor https traffic by [ConfigureForAndroid](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/)
2. I have tested android web browser can show https site(such as https://www.baidu.com) and fiddler does capture this traffic without error.

So it does work with https traffic.

---

But when I moniter target app, it can enter almost every page except the `X` page. Only see three or four https requests in fiddler every time I try, all headers likes:

```
CONNECT 180.97.93.28:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: 180.97.93.28:443
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: BDNuomiAppAndroid


HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 17:07:54.262
Connection: close
```

The content is like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 17:07:54.262
Connection: close

Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.

Secure Protocol: Tls12
Cipher: Aes128 128bits
Hash Algorithm: Sha1 160bits
Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 256bits

== Server Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=baidu.com, OU=service operation department., O="BeiJing Baidu Netcom Science Technology Co., Ltd", L=beijing, S=beijing, C=CN

[Issuer]
  CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US

[Serial Number]
  01A00C5992A0A1426F751433BD5CBF

[Not Before]
  2016/8/15 8:00:00

[Not After]
  2017/8/17 7:59:59

[Thumbprint]
  B502436275C8874F1023DB92E30472DD597159E0

[SubjectAltNames]
*.baidu.com, *.baifubao.com, *.bdstatic.com, *.hao123.com, *.nuomi.com, *.bce.baidu.com, *.eyun.baidu.com, *.map.baidu.com, baidu.com, baifubao.com, www.baidu.cn, www.baidu.com.cn, click.hm.baidu.com, log.hm.baidu.com, cm.pos.baidu.com, wn.pos.baidu.com, update.pan.baidu.com, mct.y.nuomi.com
```

Seems be blocked, so I wonder:

1. Do I miss some configurition to fiddler?
2. If it has a way to detect I am using fiddler to monitor the traffic and deny my access?
3. If `2` is true, how?
4. If `3` exists, how to overcome it?

**Update:**

I think the problem is fiddler's ca cert, maybe a ca black list on remote server ?

Comment: Here is something for #2 & #3. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36420/how-can-a-website-find-my-real-ip-address-while-im-behind-a-proxy

And this may somewhat answer #4
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100550/how-does-a-website-detect-proxy

Comment: @Sid But fiddler is design for sniff http traffic, would not make such mistake , it actually acts as a transparent proxy. And I don't see any header contain `X-Forwarded-For` or something would reveal I behind a proxy.

Comment: Whats the app you are looking at? I can give it a shot.

Comment: @Sid Thanks for your kindness, but I afraid you can't help me. Because the app is O2O Group-Buying App named "百度糯米" in China, without English version, and not available on google play.